# "git fetch" does not work

Tags: git, dvcs, gitorious

`git@gitorious.org:~porton/texmacs/texmacs-porton.git` is my repository containing a clone of the main TeXmacs repository `git://gitorious.org/texmacs/texmacs.git` with my changes (not accepted to the main repository).

I run the following commands:

```
$ git clone git@gitorious.org:~porton/texmacs/texmacs-porton.git

$ cd texmacs-porton

$ git fetch --verbose --progress https://git.gitorious.org/texmacs/texmacs.git
```

The last `get fetch` outputs nothing and as it seems to me does not create any new branches.

Please help me to merge from the main TeXmacs repository to my own.

Is it a bug of git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
git remote add official git://gitorious.org/texmacs/texmacs.git
git fetch official
```

- `git://` is much faster
- by giving the remote a name, fetch can create remote branches

Comment: Ah, yes, makes sense. Without a remote name it would have nowhere in refs/remotes to place remote tracking branches.

Comment: "by giving the remote a name (by using `remote add`), fetch can create remote branches" -- this is a key insight.  Without `remote add`, fetch tends to report success, but accomplish nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is likely your URL. You're using `https://` (which results in a 404) when you should be using `git://`.

The following works for me:

```
git fetch git://git.gitorious.org/texmacs/texmacs.git
```

Comment: 1. It does not work with both https:// and git://. 2. How did you check for yourself that it does work? Has it produced output? Has it created a new branch?

Comment: @porton I simply checked by attempting to clone your `https://` URI, which failed (specifically, hung indefinitely) vs cloning your URI using the `git://` protocol specifier, which worked instantly.

Comment: This does not make sense. Cloning works for me. The thing which does not work is "git fetch" and it does not depend on the used protocol, GIT or HTTPS.

Comment: @porton There's no reason to assume it will work with `http://`. Git *can* use HTTP as a transport, but the server doesn't have to support it.